# Which openGL ES frameworks are available to use for 2D user interfaces with iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, opengl-es

Currently I start learning openGL ES, but I wonder what kind of helpful frameworks are out there to get things done faster?

Answer (score 2):

There's an iPhone gaming framework developed by Jeff Lamarche (who has published a book for iPhone beginners) that uses OpenGLES. I'm currently trying to use the framework myself.

Here's his official release:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/updated-opengl-es-xcode-project.html

And a tutorial that uses the code (although it's very lengthly):
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Blogs/iPhone_gaming_1.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=1541633&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=3071377

Answer (score 1):

I would say these are the top two free frameworks. Both are aimed at gaming but could probably be adapted for other purposes.

[Oolong Engine](http://oolongengine.com/)

[Sio2](http://sio2interactive.com/HOME/HOME.html)

As for paid engines I think this is the best

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I've been very happy with Cocos2d.  http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/